# loading images with a Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to use a Promise.all to load images,
but the status remain desperate for 'none'

```js
const images =
        { menu: { img:null , path:'images/Menu.png', status:'none' }
        , map : { img:null , path:'images/a6.png'  , status:'none' }
        };

function loadImage( ref ) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {

    console.log( ref.path );

    ref.img = new Image();

    ref.img.onload  =_=>{ ref.status='OK';  resolve() };
    ref.img.onerror =_=>{ ref.status='bad'; resolve() };

    ref.img.src = ref.path;
  });
}

Promise
  .all([ loadImage(images.menu), loadImage(images.map) ])
  .then()
    {
    console.log('menu:', images.menu.status);
    console.log('map :', images.map.status);
    };
```

console:

> images/Menu.png
>     images/a6.png
>     menu: none
>     map : none

what did I miss?

(JS-es6 only please)

Comment: try moving the last console logging inside the `then` function like this: `.then(function() { /* code here */ })`

Comment: @MaxxikCZ, you right ! thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax

```
Promise
  .all([ loadImage(images.menu), loadImage(images.map) ])
  .then()
    {
    console.log('menu:', images.menu.status);
    console.log('map :', images.map.status);
    };
```

isn't right. I think you mean this:

```
Promise
  .all([ loadImage(images.menu), loadImage(images.map) ])
  .then(function(){
     console.log('menu:', images.menu.status);
     console.log('map :', images.map.status);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`then()` needs a callback function to work. You are just running `then()` with any callback.

Try this:

```
Promise
  .all([ loadImage(images.menu), loadImage(images.map) ])
  .then(function(){
    console.log('menu:', images.menu.status);
    console.log('map :', images.map.status);
  });
```

When all the promises end, will call the function that you pass as a `then()` callback. Note how I call `then(function...)` with a function as an argument.