# How to get component loaded state in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a simple Pokedex that shows all pokemon, I am displaying all the cards by using a map function on an array of pokemon objects like this:

```js
{pokemons.results.map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <div key={i} className="lg:w-1/4 md:w-1/2 p-4 w-full">
                  <Link href={"/"}>
                    <a className="block relative rounded-lg overflow-hidden hover:cursor-pointer hover:shadow-xl hover:shadow-poke-blue/50 p-4  bg-poke-blue group">
                      <img
                        alt="ecommerce"
                        className="object-cover object-center w-full block"
                        src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/${el.url
                          .replace("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/", "")
                          .replace("/", "")}.png`}
                        height="400px"
                        onError={addDefaultSrc}
                      />

                      <div className="mt-4">
                        <h2 className="group-hover:underline text-white text-center title-font text-lg font-medium uppercase">
                          {el.name}
                        </h2>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

there is an image tag in the div of the card which displays the image of the pokemon like this:
[image: screenshot]

I also added the functionality to search pokemon based on the name. The problem is as soon as the state changes the images don't change immediately which makes sense since the images don't get downloaded instantly. For a few minutes, it shows the image of the previously loaded pokemon image at the same place.
[image]

So I need help to show a loader for the time till all the images have loaded. I will use a loader that I already have I need to know how to get the event of all images loaded.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem. This code is a prime example of why an array index is not suitable to use as `key` for a changing list. Just use `key={el.name}` for instance and the correct images will show just fine.

Comment: @ChrisG the problem is not displaying the wrong image it is that I want to get the event that all images are loaded or not thnx for replying tho

Comment: Do you really want to make every user stare at a loader first until all 1100+ images are loaded if maybe all they want is to look up a specific Pokemon for instance? I'd let the user interact with my website asap and use placeholder images behind the actual ones.

Comment: @ChrisG ok that is true too but still my question is unanswered on how do I get a state of all images loaded

Comment: There are existing answers, and this isn't really React specific either. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158817/loading-images-with-a-promise-all (note that you don't have to use the Image you preloaded; preloading an image puts it in the browser's cache so you can just preload anywhere in your app, discard the `Image`s and move on to removing the loader)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `onLoad` event on the `img` tag you should be able to just add a `loaded` property on each item in the local copy of the data, then just updated the loaded property onLoad and then make a derived `loaded` variable

```
const loaded = images().every(img => img.loaded)
```

Also @Chris G's message about the keys is entirely correct and should be followed, I was just answering the question

Comment: I dont have a local copy I am using an external API for ALL the data

Comment: `const pokemonsLocal = useState(pokemons.results)`

You  may need to split it into a nested component due to hook rules also you could do 

`useEffect(() => setPokemonsLocal(pokemons.results))`